# What is the purpose of taking the linear approximation of this tangent function for estimating the measurement error?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

[image]

$h$ = distance from ground to eye of a person, who measured the angle to the top of the building with a protractor.

$θ$ = from the eye to the top of the building.

$x$ = distance of the person from the building.

$y$ = the height of the building

The equation to find the height of the building is given by: $y = h + x ⋅ \tan(θ)$

---

The following introduces the error values and solves for $Δy$:

$$\tan(θ + Δθ) = \frac{(y + Δy) - (h + Δh)}{x + Δx}$$

$$\tan(θ + Δθ) = \frac{Δy - Δh + (y - h)}{x + Δx}$$

$$\tan(θ + Δθ) = \frac{Δy - Δh + x ⋅ tan(θ)}{x + Δx}$$ --> Uses the fact that $\tan(θ) = \frac{(y - h)}{x}$

$$Δy = Δh + (x + Δx) ⋅ \tan(θ + Δθ) - x ⋅ \tan(θ)$$

---

Now, the course I'm taking goes on to say "to get a sense of the order of the error, let's find the linear approximation of $\tan(θ + Δθ)$" and then plugs it in the same place so that:

$Δy \approx Δh + (x + Δx)(\tan(θ) + \sec^2(θ)Δθ) - x ⋅ \tan(θ)$

My question is, why is this substitution done? How does it affect the formula? Why does it help solve the for the error? Why find the linear approximation for this but not any other term in the formula? The course I'm taking does not adequately explain why this needs to be done.

Comment: The goal is to get something linear in $\Delta \theta$.

Comment: @lulu Why is this the goal? How does this make it linear in $Δθ$ when compared to what it was before the change?

Comment: We want to understand how the function changes for small changes in $\theta$. Thus the goal is to get an expression of the form $f(\theta +\Delta \theta)\approx  f(\theta)+C\Delta \theta $ where $C$ may depend on any of the other variables or parameters in the problem, but not on $\Delta \theta$.  In the first pass, your expression had a $\tan(\theta +\Delta \theta)$ term which obscures the dependence.

Comment: Keep in mind that these functions (like the trig functions) are hard to evaluate.  If you could evaluate them exactly, then there would be no need for approximations.  The point of this sort of thing is to get down to an approximation we can easily compute.

Comment: @lulu when it's in the form $f(θ)+CΔθ$, why is C not dependent on Δθ?

Comment: I said that's the goal, to get the approximation in that form.  That is easy to compute for particular choices of $\Delta \theta$.

Comment: Should add:  later on, you'll get approximations which depend on higher powers of $\Delta \theta$, so you can have something like $f(\theta)=c_0+c_1\Delta \theta +c_2\Delta \theta^2+\cdots$.  Again, polynomial expressions like that are easily computed.  But, it makes sense to start with linear approximations.

Comment: @lulu Can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion in the comments:

The point here is to achieve a *linear* approximation.  That is we want an expression of the form $$f(\theta +\Delta\theta)-f(\theta)\approx C(\theta) \Delta \theta$$

Where $C(\theta)$ may depend on $\theta$, or any of the other parameters of the problem, but not on $\Delta \theta$.

The idea behind this is that we wish to avoid having to evaluate transcendental functions, like the trig functions, anywhere except at special values.  The approximation gives us am easily computable way of estimating the value of those functions near special values.